# How inject dependencies into a Service process using Dagger 2.11+?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm want inject my singletons objets into a service class.

I tried, creating a module to each service and including then on AppComponent using the @ContributesAndroidInjector.

Follow an example of how I'm doing that.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        ServiceBuilder.class
})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();

    }

    void inject(ApplicationController app);
}

@Module(includes = DataManagerModule.class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    BaseSchedulerProvider provideSchedulerProvider() {
        return SchedulerProvider.getInstance();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SessionManager provideSessionManager(Application application) {
        return SessionManagerImpl.from(application);
    }

}

@Module
public abstract class ServiceBuilder {

    @PerService
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MyService bindMyService();

}

public class MyService extends IntentService {

    @Inject
    SessionManager sessionManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    }

}
```

I'm following the same strategy for my activities and fragments, but for services is not working and I don`t know the error.

EDIT 1: Adding error:

Hi, I did forget of write on my example. There is no error, but the instance expected (SessionManager sessionManager) keep null.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What error message are you getting? BTW you don't have any annotated `@Inject` fields in your Service

Comment: Hi, I did forget of write on my example. There is no error, but the instance expected (SessionManager sessionManager) keep null.